# Windows 7 preview images won't show

Tags: windows-7, images, windows-explorer

This used to happen before: I open a folder with images and if I have large icons it used to show me small images of what the actual image is,

but now: when I open the folder sometimes it shows me the small images for like a second and then the images all disappear and I get the standard icons.

How can I get it back to the way it used to be? Every time I enter a folder with images I want to see the small images of what the picture is please!

Comment: Ok, tried all you wrote... didnt work ;(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**check the folder view first**. From an explorer in the **Organise menu** select **folder and search options** go to the **View** tab, in there see if the first thing **[ ] Always Show Icons not thumbnails** is unchecked . . If it is already unchecked , switch it one way, and ok your way out, then switch it back. . . In the same place temporarily turn off **[ ] Display file icon on thumbnails** which is an overlay, that shouldnt effect it.

**Per User setting** for the same thing. In the start menu find **computer** right click bring up the **properties** in there click on **advanced system settings** go to the **advanced** tab, in **performance** click on settings in the **Visual Effects** tab  you have **[X] show thumbnails instead of Icons** check it. Now this makes no sence, because I had that unchecked, and I am seeing the thumbnails?

**Cleanup Thumbs**: Next is to try and clear out the old thumbnails. find the diskclean tool by typing this into either **search or run** `cleanmgr.exe` , select the drive your having problems with, then clean up the **Thumbnails**.